# Autofac в приложении Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, di, autofac

Пишу прилодение на WinForms, используя Autofac. Есть форма:

```
    public partial class CreatePurchaseForm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        List<Book> _selectedBooksList;
        ISaleBookService _saleBookService;
        public delegate CreatePurchaseForm CreatPurchase(List<Book> list
                                            , ISaleBookService saleBookService);
        public CreatePurchaseForm(List<Book> list,ISaleBookService saleBookService)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _selectedBooksList = list;
            _saleBookService= saleBookService;
        }
    }
```

Её резолвлю из главной формы по нажатию кнопки

```
        private void btnCreatePurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedRows = GetBookListView.GetSelectedRows();
            var listOfPuchaseBooks = new List<Book>();
            foreach (var row in selectedRows)
            {
                if(GetBookListView.GetRow(row) is not Book bookToPurchase)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                listOfPuchaseBooks.Add(bookToPurchase);
            }
            using (var form = _lifetimeScope.Resolve<Owned<CreatePurchaseForm>>())
            {
                form.Value.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

При этом "разрезолвливается" сервис через интерфейс ISaleBookService. Но мне нужно в вызываемую форму передать список listOfPurchaseBooks. Никак не могу взять в толк как мне его передать в форму?

Comment: Чтобы что-то зарезолвить из контейнера, надо это что-то сначала туда зарегистрировать. Поизучайте MVP (Model-View-Presenter), и вообще практику использования IoC. Если вы будете таким образом закидывать через него зависимости, то с контейнером будет ещё больше путаницы, чем без него. В первую очередь этот вопрос возник из-за того что имеет место попытка нетипичного использования контейнера.

Comment: А так, создайте публичное свойство, присвойте туда значение, что мешает это сделать?

Comment: Все сервисы у меня зарегистрированы, зарегистрирована и форма. С сервисами всё без проблем работает, но тут вопрос как мне передать именно список  в конструктор (или, может, как-то ещё)? Из кода видно, что я не создаю непосредственно объект формы, а резолвлю её. Можете обяснить, в чём нетипичность использования контейнера в коде?

Comment: В том что контейнер используется в точке сборки приложения (composition root) и далее уничтожается как только загрузка компонентов приложения завершена. Во время использования приложения контейнер нигде не живет, его просто нет. Конечно в огромных проектах типа самого Visual Studio таких контейнеров может быть много для разных задач. Но в обычно делается именно так как я сказал выше. Если нужно что-то передавать между формами, значит нужен сервис, который этим занимается, что-то типа сервиса сообщений. Вы не можете просто так взять и запихнуть зависимость не изменяя конструктор формы.

Comment: Ну так же вы не сможете запихнуть что-либо в контейнер, который уже собран и используется. Зарегать экземпляр можно только в билдере. Так работает любой контейнер. Передайте через свойство, писал же. После резолва `form.Books = list; form.ShowDialog();`. И снова, чтобы не лепить костыли, почитайте про MVP. У вас не должно быть никаких `List<Book>` в форме в принципе. View не должно хранить данные, оно должно их только отображать.

Comment: Согласен, что форма не должна хранить данные, управлять данными должны сервисы, но, касаясь именно данной задачи, я не могу сообразить  как мне через сервис передать этот список из формы в форму. Если примерно направите, буду благодарен.

Comment: Я же вам говорил, создайте публичное свойство в форме и перед вызовом ShowDialog закиньте в него данные. Старым дедовским способом минуя контейнер.

Comment: У меня весь смысл в том, что нужно использовать контейнер. И именно Autofac.  Прочитал в документации про Delegate Factory. Но пока реализация не удаётся. Или я не в ту сторону вообще смотрю?

Comment: Удаление зуба мудрости через задний проход это называется, не преувеличение. Вы полностью игнорируя освновной шаблон проектирования приложения, например MVP, пытаетесь налепить костылей из того что вообще для другого используется. Для этой задачи не нужен контейнер, так как вам в принципе никаких данных передавать в форму не должно быть надо. Но если очень хочется, смотрите в любую сторону. Странный вопрос задаете: я указываю на проблемные места, вы типа их понимаете, но все равно продолжаете ломиться туда, куда ломились.

Comment: С главной формы мне нужно мне нужно забрать данные из gridView и передать их в Gridview другой формы. То есть по Вашему мне нужен сервис, который заберет данные из одного и передаст в другой, правильно я Вас понял? Но эти данные должны же где-то сохраниться!) Вот в этом у меня загвоздка.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter

Comment: Поздновато, но все же. Для свободной передачи данных между любыми формами независимо от их жизненного цикла, используйте [ApplicationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). Там же можно и резолвить зависимости из контейнера, но в десктопных приложениях, а тем более в WinForms, имхо, ioc-контейнеры лишние, кода столько же или больше, а понимания что происходит в коде на порядок меньше.